# How can I fix a missing activesupport 3.2.12 gem error in Chef 11?

Tags: chef

Symptom:  In the Chef Server 11 user interface (UI), when clicking the **"Edit"** link on a user (ie: *'hxxp://chef.example.com/users/admin/edit'*), the following error shows up:

```
ERROR: No such file or directory - /opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml
```

Inspecting the server's filesystem reveals that `/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13` exists, but the server seems to be looking for version `3.2.12`.  The `Gemfile` for chef-server-webui has `gem "rails", "~> 3.2.13"`.

Restarting the Chef Server with `chef-server-ctl restart` does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `chef-server-ctl restart` does not restart the [`unicorn`](https://rubygems.org/gems/unicorn) process.  Killing all unicorn processes on the system should cause them to automatically restart.

To kill all unicorn processes:

```
sudo ps aux | grep unicorn | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | sudo xargs kill
```

Comment: I will all the unicorns.... Still having the issue:
```
Failure/Error: })
     I18n::InvalidLocaleData:
       can not load translations from /home/blueserver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327-turbo@symphony/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /home/blueserver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327-turbo@symphony/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml>
```